# Why does Docker define invalid IP address of service?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have web-app with PHP and database in docker-compose file:

```yml
version: '2'

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge

services:

  yii2-app:
    build:
      context: ./web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - default
    depends_on:
      - yii2-db
      - queue
    environment:
      DB_NAME: ${WEB_DB_NAME}
      DB_USERNAME: ${WEB_DB_USERNAME}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${WEB_DB_PASSWORD}

  yii2-db:
    image: mysql:5.7.16
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    networks:
      - default
    expose:
      - "3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${WEB_DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${WEB_DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - "./web/db:/var/lib/mysql"
  ...
```

When I start services via `docker-compose up` my PHP-app makes db migrations. But this error occured in database connection:

```
Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.21.0.8' (using password: YES)'
```

It's strange, because in my PHP-app I use name of db service `yii2-db` and docker by itself to define the correct IP.

I connect to my PHP-app container via

```
docker exec -it passportrecognition_yii2-app_1 bash
```

and check mysql connection via mysql-client

```
mysql -h yii2-db -u root -p
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.21.0.8' (using password: YES)
```

But `172.21.0.8` is not the IP of my db, it's the IP of my PHP-app. That is PHP-app make db-connect to itself.

Database IP is `172.21.0.4` as shown with this `ping` command:

```
ping yii2-db
PING yii2-db (172.21.0.4): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.21.0.4: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.145 ms
```

And another strange moment: when I connect directly on database IP `172.21.0.4`, the following error occurs:

```
bash-4.4# mysql -h 172.21.0.4 -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.21.0.8' (using password: YES)
```

Why can't I connect to my database? Why does Docker define an invalid IP for the db service?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have found the reason:

I tested starting the services with different environment variables for db. And after that I shut the services down, changed the db name, username and password, and started the services again.

But I forgot that db folder `/var/lib/mysql` is mounted in a volume, and it remembered my previous data; everything was mixed up. So it's not problem in network, it's mixed data in mysql (different passwords for the same user).